# QT programming CSV read and write from specific files

Tags: android, c++, qt, csv

I am a newbie to QT and at the moment struggling with "read and write CSV file from QT" I have 4 questions with it.
I have read the link of [Parsing through a csv file in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318631/parsing-through-a-csv-file-in-qt), but doesn't really answer my questions.

Suppose i have the CSV file as:

1,2,3,

4,5,6,

7,8,9,

10,11,12,

13,14,15,

16,17,18,

- how do you display number "5" in qDebug?
- how to read number "7", "8", "9" at the same time?
- how to replace number "12" with "50"?
- how to replace number "13", "14", "15" with, "73", "74", "75"?
- and how to add a new line after number"18"?

Thank you very very much for your help! ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing through a csv file in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318631/parsing-through-a-csv-file-in-qt)

Comment: It does answer your first concern: reading a CSV file in Qt.  I hope you know how to write a file in Qt and how to manipulate data in C++/Qt. It is not the intention that we write your assignments.

Comment: Hi stefaanv, thank you for your comment. To be honest i'm not really sure how to manipulate the file.  The link you gave to me is to read the column. instead, i would like to know how to read the row.

By the way, it is not an assignment or a project. it just for self-learning. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is so old but I want to answer for future reference.

1-) You can show 5 in qDebug() using readLine() and split() functions.

```
...
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();   //I assume you already created reading stage.
        qDebug()<< (line.split(',').first[1]); //This prints every second character of each line.
```

2-) As I mentioned in the previous question,

```
QByteArray line = file.readLine();   //I assume you already created reading stage.
       qDebug()<< (line.split(',')); //This prints every line
```

3-4) I don't know -not sure- whether they can be changed or not. Because you need the exact location of values that you want to change, maybe QAbstractItem or any other Item classes may help.