# can qt or C++ read excel without office excel installed or other prerequisite framwork

Tags: c++, excel, qt, visual-c++

everyone. I have a problem with qt in reading excel.

I have written a app which will read some excel file by `QAxObject` , and it works.

But I want to deploy this program in static library. I find my app can't work when the office software is't installed.

I want to know if there exsits someway which can read the excel when there is no prerequisite， or is therr some lib I can integrated to my app.

thanks so much to your attention

Comment: You have to implement your own CSV reader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318631/parsing-through-a-csv-file-in-qt

Comment: You mean a excel file is in CSV format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a good website which may be useful for the others.
https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format